# why 128bit variables should be aligned to 16Byte boundary

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, assembly, x86

As we know, X86 CPU has a 64bit data bus. My understanding is that CPU can't access to arbitrary address. The address that CPU could access to is a integral multiple of the width of its data bus. For the performance, variables should start at(aligned to) these addresses to avoid extra memory access. 32bit variables aligned to 4Byte boundry will be automatically aligned to 8Byte(64bit) boundry, which corresponds to x86 64bit data bus. But why compilers align 128bit variables to 16Byte boundry? Not the 8Byte boundry?

Thanks

Let me make things more specific. Compilers use the length of a variable to align it. For example, if a variable has 256bit length, Complier will align it to 32Byte boundry. I don't think there is any kind of CPU has that long data-bus. Furthermore, common DDR memories only transfer 64bit data one time, despite of the cache, how could a memory fill up CPU's wider data-bus? or only by means of cache?

Comment: "As we know, X86 CPU has a 64bit data bus" - that's not true. x86 says nothing about data-bus sizes. Modern processors actually have larger data bus widths than that.

Comment: Processor don't read data from the data bus, they read it from cache.  A 16-byte alignment is required to avoid straddling a cache line boundary.

Comment: @Mysticial I think the most popular x86 CPUs currently have 64bit data bus, aren't they?

Comment: @iqapple Nope. Intel Core 2, Nehalem, and Sandy Bridge processors have 128-bit wide load/store ports. Not sure about AMD's though, but I think they also have 128-bit wide load/store ports since K8. Data busses between cache levels and to memory are even large. (think cache line sizes)

Comment: @HansPassant I think the data-bus is the only means for CPU to get data, no matter where the data are located in.

Comment: 32-bit variables are aligned to a 4-byte boundary, there is no need to align them to an 8-byte boundary on any CPU.

Comment: @iqapple "data-bus is the only means for CPU to get data" - Yes, but if they are cached on the way, then data bus size will have no influence on variable alignment

Comment: @j_kubik So what affact variable alignment?

Comment: @iqapple Hmm... compiler? Every processor in x86 family s slightly different, so making statements about entire family is pointless. Afaik x86 does not ENFORCE any alignment at all, it's just that some alignments will work faster than the others. Most of alignment rules are present throughout entire x86 processors family, and compiler vendors implement them so their code works faster. It is not anyhow specified where those rules come from, or do they even apply for every x86 processor - some might even allow additional fast-alignments.

Comment: @markgz: I think some old 64-bit Cray supercomputers had 32-bit values aligned to 64-bit boundaries, since the CPU didn't support any smaller data sizes.

Comment: True.  I guess I meant to say any modern CPU.

Comment: using the definition of a byte as 8 bits then 128 / 8 = 16.  Align on 128 bit boundary = align on 16 byte boundary, they are the same statement.  align on 64 bit boundary = align on 8 byte boundary.  align on 128 bit boundary != align on 8 byte boundary. 128 = 2 to the power 7 so aligned on a 128 bit boundary means (8 = 2 to the power 3, 7-3 = 4) the lower 4 bits of the byte address must be zero.  0x10 is 16 byte, is 128 bit aligned.  0x18 is not 128 bit aligned 0x20 is 128 bit aligned, 0x28, 0x21, 0x24 are not 0x30 is.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp : from the question it is clear that "any CPU" here really means "any x86 CPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are so many different processor models that I am going to answer this only in theoretical and general terms.

Consider an array of 16-byte objects that starts at an address that is a multiple of eight bytes but not of 16 bytes. Let’s suppose the processor has an eight-byte bus, as indicated in the question, even if some processors do not. However, note that at some point in the array, one of the objects must straddle a page boundary: Memory mapping commonly works in 4096-byte pages that start on 4096-byte boundaries. With an eight-byte-aligned array, some element of the array will start at byte 4088 of one page and continue up to byte 7 of the next page.

When a program tries to load the 16-byte object that crosses a page boundary, it can no longer do a single virtual-to-physical memory map. It has to do one lookup for the first eight bytes and another lookup for the second eight bytes. If the load/store unit is not designed for this, then the instruction needs special handling. The processor might abort its initial attempt to execute the instruction, divide it into two special microinstructions, and send those back into the instruction queue for execution. This can delay the instruction by many processor cycles.

In addition, as Hans Passant noted, alignment interacts with cache. Each processor has a memory cache, and it is common for cache to be organized into 32-byte or 64-byte “lines”. If you load a 16-byte object that is 16-byte aligned, and the object is in cache, then the cache can supply one cache line that contains the needed data. If you are loading 16-byte objects from an array that is not 16-byte aligned, then some of the objects in the array will straddle two cache lines. When these objects are loaded, two lines must be fetched from the cache. This may take longer. Even if it does not take longer to get two lines, perhaps because the processor is designed to provide two cache lines per cycle, this can interfere with other things that a program is doing. Commonly, a program will load data from multiple places. If the loads are efficient, the processor may be able to perform two at once. But if one of them requires two cache lines instead of the normal one, then it blocks simultaneous execution of other load operations.

Additionally, some instructions explicitly require aligned addresses. The processor might dispatch these instructions more directly, bypassing some of the tests that fix up operations without aligned addresses. When the addresses of these instructions are resolved and are found to be misaligned, the processor must abort them, because the fix-up operations have been bypassed.

Comment: I know you are right, even if some points are esoteric to me.

Comment: IMO, most of this answer, while in itself being true, is irrelevant to the qustion which was "But why compilers align 128bit variables to 16Byte boundry?". The answer to the that question is simply that the hardware requires it to be so, the compiler doesn't do it not because it is more efficient but because any other way won't work. When you say "Consider an array of 16-byte objects that starts at an address that is a multiple of eight bytes but not of 16 bytes.", well that just won't work (because the cpu hardware doesn't support it) regardless of whether the array crosses a page boundary.

Comment: Actually it depends on what the question meant by "variable". I was thinking of 128 variables like __m128i. If it is in regard to things like `struct foo {char x[128];};` then I agree with Eric.

Comment: @user2151446: The hardware does support unaligned access, via instructions such as `movups`. It would be perfectly feasible for a C implementation to support unaligned 16-byte SIMD objects. Programs using such an implementation would typically be slow, but they would work. So the choice about whether to use aligned addresses or not is not one of possibility or hardware support but one of efficiency.

Comment: Eric you overstate the importance of data alignment. Some, backed up by experimental evidence on modern x86 processors (i.e. Core i7), state **there is no performance penalty for reading or writing misaligned memory operands**. It would be fairer to say that in extreme cases non-aligned data will really hurt, but generally on x86 doesn't matter much. As for 128 bit data, which was the topic of the question, to say that SIMD intructions work on aligned data because one of the instructions can copy the data to an aligned location doesn't change the fact the SSE2 HW needs data to be aligned.

Comment: This link was supposed to be in my previous comment: http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2012/05/31/data-alignment-for-speed-myth-or-reality/

Comment: @user2151446: My answer describes some mechanisms by which alignment affects performance. It does not evaluate the importance of those mechanisms, aside from relating that the mechanisms can cause some number of cycles of delay in certain situations. If you can point out the specific sentence that overstates the importance and is incorrect, then I will correct it. If you cannot point out such a sentence, then please change your vote down to a vote up.

Comment: @user2151446: The `movups` instruction does not move data to an alignment location in memory. It is a load/store instruction that loads data from an unaligned address to an SSE register or that stores data from an SSE register to an unaligned address. The fact that it exists proves that the hardware is capable of loading and storing unaligned data.

Answer (score 5):

One reasons is that most SSE2 instructions on X86 require the data to be 128 bit aligned. This design decision would have been made for performance reasons and to avoid overly complex (and hence slow and big) hardware.

Comment: I think this is probably right.  I'm stuck here in a loop trying to figure out which compilers automatically align the __m128i type that is used for vectorized SIMD computation.